# Better solution search other than forEach

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to list object and a search needs to be by comma separated string. I have added following  `forEach` method, i would like to know is there any single line solution for this.

```
this.props.items.map((item, key) => (
        this.props.campaign_name.split(",").forEach(function(entry) {
              ( item.campaign_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(entry.toLowerCase())  )?true:false
        }.bind(this))

))
```

Comment: have you ever tried to use lodash?

Comment: The code you have doesn't do anything useful. Why are you using `.bind(this)` here?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use filter `this.props.campaign_name.split(",").filter(entry => item.campaign_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(entry.toLowerCase()) !== -1 )`